# Issues while working with google-translate-api library for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, translation, google-translate

I am a beginner to javascript.I am trying to detect language and translate language using [google-translate-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api)

I want to use google translate API for free that's why I want to use it. But when I run any code like this below,

```
const translate = require('google-translate-api');

translate('Ik spreek Engels', {to: 'en'}).then(res => {
    console.log(res.text);
    //=> I speak English
    console.log(res.from.language.iso);
    //=> nl
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

I get this error.

```
{ Error
    at F:\Extensionproject\testTranslate\node_modules\google-translate-api\index.js:105:17
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) code: 'BAD_REQUEST' }
```

I have tried more google translate API library from GitHub. None of this working.
I tried this library too! [another google-translate-api library](https://github.com/k3rn31p4nic/google-translate-api)   But getting this.

```
{ HTTPError
    at translate (F:\Extensionproject\testTranslate\node_modules\@k3rn31p4nic\google-translate-api\src\index.js:148:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  name: 'HTTPError',
  statusCode: 429,
  statusMessage: 'Too Many Requests' }
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at library github page - https://github.com/matheuss/google-translate-api, you could see that project is outdated, and there a lot of issues, with the same as yours - https://github.com/matheuss/google-translate-api/issues/70.

I recommend you to use official Google's Translate API. You can find how to use Node JS with Google Translate API [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-translate).

How to use it:

First of all, you need to install the library:

```
npm install @google-cloud/translate
```

Then, to use it:

```
async function someFunction() {
    // Imports the Google Cloud client library
    const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate');

    // Instantiates a client
    const translate = new Translate({projectId});

    // The text to translate
    const text = 'Hello, world!';

    // The target language
    const target = 'fr';

    // Translates some text into French
    const [translation] = await translate.translate(text, target);
    console.log(`Text: ${text}`);
    console.log(`Translation: ${translation}`);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @BSeitkazin. I have used your code with the projectId =  'translate-api-242605' . But I am getting the error "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function" If I remove " await I am getting another error "TypeError: translate.translate is not a function or its return value is not iterable"

Comment: @MituVinci, updated example. You should post the example code inside some `async` function.

Comment: @MituVinci, if answer was helpful, please mark it as right answer. If you have another problem, just create another question. Thanks.

Comment: your code works fine. But it needed Google translate API key which is not free. However, I tried this library https://github.com/k3rn31p4nic/google-translate-api in a new project directory and now it is working fine! No need any key or id. :D

Comment: @MituVinci, it is highly recommended to use official API's. Then, according to Google Translate API, it is free for 1–500,000 characters per month. I think it is enough for own project.

Comment: Ofc nobody knows what is projectId.